# REST API rule about tunneling

Tags: api, rest, web-framework, http

Just read this in the [REST API Rulebook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do): **GET and POST must not be used to tunnel other request methods**.

> Tunneling refers to **any abuse** of HTTP that masks or misrepresents a message’s intent and undermines the protocol’s transparency. A REST API must not compromise its design by misusing HTTP’s request methods in an effort to **accommodate clients with limited HTTP vocabulary**. Always make proper use of the HTTP methods as specified by the rules in this section. [highlights by me]

But then a lot of frameworks use *tunneling* to expose REST interfaces via HTML forms, since `<form>` knows only about `GET` and `POST`. My most recent example is a `MethodRewriteMiddleware` for flask (submitted by the author of the framework): http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/38/.

Any ways to comply to the "Rule" without hacks or add-ons in web frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. So if you need to, break the rule anyway.

I don't know what the big deal is. Protocols encapsulate other protocols all the time. TCP/IP for example has [***four layers*** of such abstraction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Of course, the better path is for clients to get with the program and support the HTTP verbs properly. But it's not a perfect world.

Comment: Thanks, well everybody is doing it anyway (and other protocols do it by design, as you mention it). I just was a bit surprised to find the "rule" written down so clearly.